# How can I prevent clobbering of encrypted (binary) files in Git?

Tags: git, security, encryption, version-control

We store our puppet configs in Git. Some of these files are manually gpg encrypted before commit and manually decrypted  after checkout. However, a few days ago I merged a branch that had been taken from HEAD that clobbered changes another person had made. If the file had not been encrypted git would have merged the changes correctly.

This file contains sensitive credentials that caould take systems offline if incorrect so its important that we can diff and view changes over time.

how can I restore the visibility, and git's advanced ability to merge changes, while still maintaining the security of the file contents?

Comment: Submitting secrets with the source codes could be considered a bad practice in general.

Comment: keeping the configs with the rest of the configuration is convenient, encryption allows us to do that. But seems that git is not designed to handle encryption natively and we loose merging features. What do you suggest as a better process?

Answer (score 0):

Git lets you set up custom converters for binary (or any) files to preprocess them before they hit `git-diff`. You could use this feature to unencrypt the files whenever Git is diffing them.

Here's an example of this feature, which is called [`textconv`](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Textconv):

> .gitconfig must indicate the command to execute for the the textconv driver:
>
> ```
> [diff "odf"]
>     textconv=odt2txt
> ```
>
> .gitattributes must associate files to a driver:
>
> ```
> *.odf diff=odf
> ```

This example uses `textconv` to convert `*.odf` files, but you could use any function you want any process any file.

This approach would at least let you examine the diffs while merging as a sanity check.